# SQL Server query is not returning any rows

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to read a single column from a single row. After executing the query no rows are returned but there are fields.

When I look at the reader HasRows is false but the field count is 1.

```
string sql = "select userid from aspnet_Membership where loweredemail = '@email'";

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, THOGConnection);

string emailAddress = (string)account["ree_thogemail"];
emailAddress = emailAddress.ToLower();
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailAddress);

SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    userId = (Guid)reader["userid"];
}
```

If I select all columns in the row then the field count is 21 but there are still no rows.

Why am I not returning any rows?

Thanks, Gary

Comment: You don't need to use '' around @email. Use `select userid from aspnet_Membership where loweredemail = @email`

Comment: When running the query in the management studio, does it return rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use ' around @email. Use :

```
string sql = "select userid from aspnet_Membership where loweredemail = @email"
```

Actually it returns no value, because there is no record with `loweredemail = '@email'` while there is record with for example `loweredemail = 'someone@example.com'`.
When using parameters, single quotes are not needed.

Comment: That fixed the problem. I just wonder what the sql engine was doing that it would return a column and not a row? Thanks

Comment: @Gary Actually it returns no value, because there is no record with loweredemail = '@email' while there is records with loweredemail = 'someone@example.com'. When using parameters, single quotes are not needed.

Comment: @Gary you are getting an empty result set.  The columns are returned even when there are no matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in your sql query:

```
string sql = "select userid from aspnet_Membership where loweredemail = '@email'";
```

should be like the following

```
string sql = "select userid from aspnet_Membership where loweredemail = @email";
```